# Android Thread implementation for custom View

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics, custom-view

I am trying to  make a TicTacToe game for android . But i have the following problems. 
   First and foremost i would like to ***implement threads*** to my app but i have not been succesfull ( have tried almost anything ) . 
   Secondly i would like  to know how to cope with these two errors ( i dont know if they are called errors) : ***Grow heap (frag case) to 65.24 MB for 2567824 byte-allocation***  , ***Skipped 118 frames ! The applcation may be doing too much work on its main thread*** ( though i think this would be solved with thread implementation )

```
public class DrawClass extends View {

int index;
int x, y, RectX, RectY;
// it will hold the rectangles dimensions depending on the screen dimensions
public Rect[] rectangles = new Rect[9];
// it will be our reference array as to what does each rectangle hold
char[] isFilledWith = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
// bitmaps
Bitmap empty, cross, circle;

// constructor
public DrawClass(Context context) {

    super(context);
    // setting bitmaps and calculating screen dimensions
    setBitmaps();
    Calculations(context);

}

public void setBitmaps() {// set the 3 bitmaps empty , circle , cross
    cross = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cross1);
    circle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.circle1);
    empty = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.empty1);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    // this for updates the canvas with the appropriate bitmaps cross , circle or empty 
    // depending on tyhe char array isFilledWith
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (isFilledWith[i] == ' ') {
            canvas.drawBitmap(empty, null, rectangles[i], null);
        } else if (isFilledWith[i] == 'X') {
            canvas.drawBitmap(cross, null, rectangles[i], null);
        } else if (isFilledWith[i] == 'O') {
            canvas.drawBitmap(circle, null, rectangles[i], null);
        }
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, 3 * y, paint);// 1h
        canvas.drawLine(2 * x, 0, 2 * x, 3 * y, paint);// 2h
        canvas.drawLine(0, y, 3 * x, y, paint);// 3h
        canvas.drawLine(0, 2 * y, 3 * x, 2 * y, paint);// 4h
    }
}

protected void Calculations(Context context) {
    /*
     * We calculate screen dimensions and fill the rectangles array with the
     * appropriate dimensions
     */
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    x = (width / 3);
    y = (height / 3);

    int rectanglescounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            rectangles[rectanglescounter] = new Rect((x * j), (y * i),
                    ((x * j) + x), ((y * i) + y));
            if (rectanglescounter < 8)
                rectanglescounter++;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    Log.d("Checks", "rectangles calculated");
}
// setter for the array 
public void setArray(int index, char character) {
    this.isFilledWith[index] = character;
}
// getter for the array
public char getArray(int index) {
    return isFilledWith[index];
}
// This method searches for tictactoe winning patterns .
public char checkForWinner() {
    if (isFilledWith[0] == isFilledWith[1]
            && isFilledWith[1] == isFilledWith[2]) {// 1st horizontal

        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st row win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st row win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[3] == isFilledWith[4]
            && isFilledWith[4] == isFilledWith[5]) {// 2nd horizontal

        if (isFilledWith[3] == 'X') {
            ;
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2st row win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[3] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2st row win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[6] == isFilledWith[7]
            && isFilledWith[7] == isFilledWith[8]) {// 3rd horizontal

        if (isFilledWith[6] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "3st row win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[6] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "3st row win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[0] == isFilledWith[3]
            && isFilledWith[3] == isFilledWith[6]) {// 1st vertical

        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st column win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st column win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[1] == isFilledWith[4]
            && isFilledWith[4] == isFilledWith[7]) {// 2st vertical

        if (isFilledWith[1] == 'X') {

            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2st column win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[1] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2st column win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[2] == isFilledWith[5]
            && isFilledWith[5] == isFilledWith[8]) {// 3rd vertical

        if (isFilledWith[2] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "3st column win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[2] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "3st column win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if (isFilledWith[0] == isFilledWith[4]
            && isFilledWith[4] == isFilledWith[8]) {// diagonal
        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st diagonal win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[0] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "1st diagonal win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else if ((isFilledWith[2] == isFilledWith[4] && isFilledWith[4] == isFilledWith[6])) {// diagonal

        if (isFilledWith[2] == 'X') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2nd diagonal win detected");
            return 'X';
        }
        if (isFilledWith[2] == 'O') {
            Log.d("WINNING CHECK", "2nd diagonal win detected");
            return 'O';
        }
    } else
        return ' ';
    return ' ';
}
```

}

```
public class NewGame extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

DrawClass drawing;
int movecounter = 0;
int playercounter = 0;
static {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawing = new DrawClass(this);
    //setting on touch events to correspond to this class ontouchlistener
    drawing.setOnTouchListener(this);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    setContentView(drawing);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int tempx = (int) event.getX();
    int tempy = (int) event.getY();

    // calculating where the user touched the screen so as to fill the char
    // array with the appropriate char 'x'or 'o' and then invalidate the
    // drawing
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (drawing.rectangles[i].contains(tempx, tempy)) {
            if (drawing.getArray(i) == ' ') {
                if (playercounter % 2 == 0)
                    drawing.setArray(i, 'X');
                else
                    drawing.setArray(i, 'O');
                playercounter++;
            } else if (drawing.getArray(i) != ' ')
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONT CHEAT",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // CHECKINK FOR WINNER or DRAW

            movecounter++;
            if (movecounter >= 5) {
                if (drawing.checkForWinner() == 'X') {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X WIN",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                if (drawing.checkForWinner() == 'O') {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O WIN",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                if (movecounter >= 9) {
                    Log.d("Entered Draw ", " ok ");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "IT'S A DRAW  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
            drawing.invalidate();
        } else
            continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you tried AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), Handler (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)  and read this (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Skipped 118 frames ! The applcation may be doing too much work on its main thread` you are doing to much work on the UI thread. Creating a thread or using asynctask to do the heavy work will solve this error. Take a look at this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html, it is well explained.

Comment: Hello ! The problem is i do not know how and where to implement either a thread or a handler or AsyncTask in my code . My previous tries had beedn futile .

Answer (score 0):

To help you with your struggles with threads and asynctasks you have to be more specific, but to find where the performance problem is you can use the [profiling tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) of Android.